# How to open a file based on the output of the `file` command

Tags: shell, files, mime-types, file-command

So I have a directory where I wish to open the only file in that directory that is human readable. I use `file *` to print the type of each file, and one file shows as ASCII-text. How can I redirect that specific file to cat or less to display its content?

EDIT:

Y'all are awesome. I'm trying each.

Comment: @Debian_yadav: no, he's got just one *TEXT* file among a bunch of binaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` to search for files containing ASCII text:

```
less $(file * | awk -F: '$2 ~ "ASCII text" {print $1}')
```

This actually works also for directories containing several text files.

Comment: Works as long as no filename has `:` in it.

Comment: @Kusalananda Truely true, there is always `file -0` :-)

Comment: Is there? Possibly on Linux...

Comment: @Kusalananda At least on macOS (and, according to the man page, BSD and Debian)

Comment: Well, "BSD" is actually quite a broad term nowadays. See e.g. https://man.openbsd.org/file.1

Comment: I think you'd have to double-quote the command substitution to deal with files with $IFS in their names.

Answer (score 1):

The following bash function will look through the files in the current directory; if exactly one of them reports back as being "ASCII text", then it will `cat` that file.

```
filecat() {
  local files=(./*)
  local count=0
  local filename=
  local f=
  for f in "${files[@]}"
  do
    if file "$f" 2>/dev/null | grep -q ": ASCII text$"
    then
      count=$((count + 1))
      filename="$f"
    fi
  done
  if [ "$count" -eq 1 ]
  then
    cat "$filename"
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a safe way to open what `file` thinks are text files in the current directory in `vim`.  Of course, you can change `vim` to `echo` to just print the names.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *; do
   out=$(file "$f")
   [[ "${out##*: }" =~ ASCII ]] && text_files+=("$f")
done

vim "${text_files[@]}"

exit
```

EDIT: use two `#` signs in the parameter expansion to handle filenames with a `:` in them.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`, you could define a function like:

```
 istext() [[ $(file -b --mime-type -- "${1-$REPLY}") = text/* ]]
```

Which you could then use in glob qualifiers like:

```
 less -- *(.L+0+istext)
```

To view the non-empty (`L+0` for length greater than 0) regular files (`.`) in the current directory that are text according to `file`.

Answer (score 0):

To only `less` a file if it's an ASCII text:

```
less_if_text() {
   # $1 is the file name
   if file $1 | grep -q 'ASCII .* text' ; then
     less $1
   else
     echo "Not a text file: $1"
   fi
}
```

To list text files in a naive but easy to understand way:

```
ls_texts() {
  ls -a | while read filename; do 
    (file $filename | grep -q 'ASCII .* text') && echo $filename
  done
}
```

The above is not quite fast, though. A faster way would use `file -f` to avoid multiple `file` and `grep` invocations:

```
ls_texts() {
  ls | file -f - | egrep ':\s+ASCII .* text' | while read fname
    do cut -d ':' -f 1 
  done
}
```

Comment: If they already have the filename in hand (`$1`, the parameter to your function), then they could jus tpass it to `cat` or `less` themselves.  Perhaps a more generic answer would run `file` on every file in the current (or given?) directory and go from there?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Updated the answer to include the listing of files.

Comment: [parsing ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) is tricky...

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Indeed, especially if you have file names with embedded spaces and other special characters; add `--quote-names` to alleviate it a bit.